# java.sql.SQLException: 'Infinity' is not a valid numeric or approximate numeric value

Tags: java, mysql

I am using a java function which returns a float

```
private float getEventScaledX(float eventX, float resX) {
    return (eventX * frameWidth) / resX;
}
```

While storing it under mysql db it throws exception as

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: 'Infinity' is not a valid numeric or approximate numeric value
```

Please suggest a right way to handle it at java side to stop this exception but also to get right expected result.

Comment: What values are you passing?

Comment: I guess resX is near zero

Comment: Eg. frameWidth : 400 and eventX = 320.5459899902344

Comment: @apomene Your answer seems to be the right one.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please add all relevant information to your question, or best post [mcve]. `frameWidth : 400  eventX = 320.5459899902344` should be in the question, as well as the value of `resX` (I guess it is 0, but I should not be guessing) and the `sql` statement.

Comment: @c0der & apomene : yes, both of you are right. I could see the value coming from json for resX is 0. Thank you for your quick help :)

Comment: Glad it helped. Consider removing the question if it is of no interest for future readers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here was (as reported by @c0der and @apomene ) resX coming as zero.

JAVA float data type does not throw any arithmetic exception while division by zero operation, rather returns Infinity / NaN as value. Which MySQL can't store as valid numeric type so the exception.

Checking for ( resX > 0 ) fixed my issue .